# unexplained space in math mode (left/right brackets, vphantom)

Tags: math-mode, spacing, brackets

I'm currently writing a small tool which automatically generates latex code for equations. I stumbled over the following problem, which in extremely boiled-down form looks like this:

```
\begin{align*}
a
&=
\left( \left[ \left\{ \left( b
\vphantom{x} \right.
\vphantom{x} \right.
\vphantom{x} \right.
\vphantom{x} \right. 
\\&\quad\;
%--------
c
\\&\quad\;
%--------
\left. \vphantom{x}
\left. \vphantom{x}
\left. \vphantom{x}
\left. \vphantom{x}
d
\right) \right\} \right] \right)
\\&\quad\;
%--------
\left. \left. \left. \left.
e
\right) \right\} \right] \right)
\end{align*}
```

The output contains some space for which I have no explanation:

[image]

Please let me guide you through this.

In the align environment, I have a left side (a) only in the first line, and right sides in all lines. I insert a `\quad\;` at the beginning of each line (except for the first) to jump over the space of the `=` character.

In the first line (a, b), I have four opening brackets with auto-scaling (`\left`). The `\vphantom` are required in my code to keep the vertical size of the brackets over the line breaks; they contain more complex text, but here I simply pass `x`. I compensate the four opening brackets with for virtual closing brackets (`\right.`).

In the second line (c), I just have `c` which nicely aligns below the right side of the first line. This is what I want for the third line as well.

In the third line (d) (which is actually of the form that my code generates), I have four virtual opening brackets (`\left.`) and four closing brackets. Now this line generates a lot of space before the `d`.

In the fourth line (e) I deleted all the `\vphantom` commands. Surprisingly, this reduces the space. The remaining space seems to be generated by the `\left.` commands. I could understand if this would be the space occupied by the closing brackets, but it is smaller (please compare with the first line).

So, my problem is that I want to compensate for the unwanted space in the third line by inserting a negative space (e.g. `\!`), but I have no clue how and why latex generates the space in the first place. Since the code is automatically generated and has an arbitrary number of brackets, I can't just use a negative space of fixed size.

I there anyone deeply familiar with the internal latex code to tell me what latex is doing in this case, such that I can compensate for the unwanted space? Thanks a lot!

---

Edit in response to campa: I included `\setlength{\nulldelimiterspace}{0pt}` which seems to reduce the spacing, but doesn't eliminate it completely (second example):

[image]

Comment: Null delimiters (can) have a non-zero width controlled by the primitive register `\nulldelimiterspace` (the default is something more than 1pt IIRC).

Comment: @campa: Thanks a lot. Setting length `\nulldelimiterspace` to zero actually reduces the space, but doesn't eliminate it. I edited my answer.

Comment: TeX inserts a thin space between an ordinary atom and an inner atom. So there is a thin space between `\vphantom{x}` and `\left.` Besides `\nulldelimiterspace`, this is another reason for not using indiscriminately `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks a lot. Is there a length variable connected to this thin space (which could be set to zero)?

Comment: @Ralf Yes, but you’d end up ruining several other parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to run `\setlength\nulldelimiterspace{0pt}`, load the [mleftright](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mleftright) package, *and* replace all instances of `\left` and `\right` with `\mleft` and `\mright`, respectively.

Separately, I'd replace all instances of `&\quad\;` with `&\phantom{{}={}}` in order to guarantee correct alignment.

In the following screenshot, I employ `|` merely to indicate the start and end of material on the right hand side of the (visible or hidden) `=` symbols. Observe that I've also dropped all `\vphantom{x}` directives since they don't do anything.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}    % for 'align*' environment
\usepackage{mleftright} % for '\mleft' and '\mright' macros
\begin{document}
\setlength\nulldelimiterspace{0pt}
\begin{align*}
a
&=
|\mleft( \mleft[ \mleft\{ \mleft( 
b
\mright. \mright. \mright. \mright. | \\
&\phantom{{}={}}
|b| \\
&\phantom{{}={}}
|\mleft. \mleft. \mleft. \mleft. 
b
\mright) \mright\} \mright] \mright) | 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect, that works, thanks a lot, that is really helpful!